# combining slideToggle successfully with min-height

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, css

I currently have a nicely hidden section at the top of my site which slides down upon click. The animation works great with slideToggle but I'd also like the div to cover at least the window height.

I have managed to set the window height as a variable and alter the css to reflect this but combining it with the slideToggle makes the animation jumpy.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var win = $(window).height();
  $("#hidden").css("min-height", win);
  $("a#toggle").click(function() {
   var txt = $("#hidden").is(':visible') ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
   $("#toggle").text(txt);
   $("#hidden").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HZACf/

If you remove the first two lines of the jQuery, it slides as normal.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `animate`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $hidden = $("#hidden"),
    currentHeight = $hidden.height(),
    newHeight = $(window).height();

    newHeight = (currentHeight > newHeight) ? currentHeight : newHeight;

    $("#hidden").css("height", newHeight);

    $("a#toggle").click(function () {
        var txt = $("#hidden").is(':visible') ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
        $("#toggle").text(txt);
        $("#hidden").animate({
            height : "toggle"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

I've used `animate` but you can use `slideToggle` instead as we are solely dealing with the elements' `height` now.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HZACf/4/)

Comment: Thanks @darshanags, it works but is almost as jerky as with the old method. It's hard to see on the small fiddle example but the animation is done in two distinct parts and therefore doesn't really work well. Is there anyway of setting the min-height before the toggle takes place?

Comment: why do you want to use `min-height` instead of using `height`?

Comment: in case the content exceeds the height of the window

Comment: which content? content in the `#hidden` div or the page content?

Comment: content in the #hidden div. It's a largeish form so on smaller screens, may well be longer than the window height.

Comment: That works much better, still a bit jerkier (I think) than the natural slideToggle but pretty good. Thanks darshanags! Can you put it as an answer and I can tick it?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can replace `animate` with `slideToggle` if you wish. @onjegolders